# Does Fortran 95 allow two subroutines to have the same name if the argument lists are different?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

Does the Fortran 95 standard allow two subroutines (or functions) to have the same name if the argument lists have different lengths?  For example,

```
subroutine a(i)
! code here
end subroutine a

subroutine a(j,k)
! code here
end subroutine a
```

Comment: In addition to reading Alexander Vogt's reply about INTERFACE, you should be aware that a subroutine can be called with a varying number of arguments if some of the arguments are declared OPTIONAL.

Comment: @Fortranner: Indeed. You can find an example of that in the answer of the linked post as well ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not literally as given in the question, but by using an `interface`:

```
module a_wrapper

  interface a
    module procedure a_1
    module procedure a_2
  end interface

contains
  subroutine a_1(i)
  ! code here
  end subroutine a

  subroutine a_2(j,k)
  ! code here
  end subroutine a
end module

program test
  use a_wrapper, only: a

  call a(.....)
end program
```

See also my answer to this post: [Passing different set of variables in a FORTRAN subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662064/passing-different-set-of-variables-in-a-fortran-subroutine/23662485#23662485) or M.S.B.'s answer on this post: [how to write wrapper for 'allocate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257248/how-to-write-wrapper-for-allocate)

Comment: Another example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257248/how-to-write-wrapper-for-allocate